# Using Objects in a similar way to Variables in Java

Tags: java, variables, object, global-variables

Can i use the following code? It's not throwing any error at the Object but at obj.i. Is this a legal way of using an object? Also, how many ways can i create an object other than using the normal syntax obj s = new obj();

```
public class Test {

    static int i;
    static Test obj;
    obj.i = 10; //am getting a compilation error here "Syntax error on token "i", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token"

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(i+" "+ obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? No, there is only one way to initialize an object, using `new`

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a static block around the obj.i assignment statement for this to work:

```
public class Test {
   static int i;
   static Test obj;
   static { obj.i = 10; }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(i+" "+ obj);
   }
}
```

Comment: So you're accessing the static `i` through an instance? Shouldn't you explain to the OP that it doesn't make a lot of sense? You also never initialized `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not, you didn't initialize. Furthermore you might not want to use `static`.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
int i = 10;
Test obj = new Test();
obj.setI(i);
System.out.println("my objects I = "+ obj.getI());
}
```

now in your `Test` object

```
public class Test {
private int i;


public void setI(int i) {
this.i = i;
}

public int getI() {
return this.i;
}
}
```